# Storing, retrieving binary data or bytes to and from a file for a std::deque?

Tags: c++, file, memory-management, c++11, deque

I am writing a "replay system" for a game and I'm wondering how I should store the recorded frames?

As for now I have this code / structures (note: this code is shortened):

```
struct Point4D { float x, y, z, w; };
struct Point3D { float x, y, z; };
struct Point2D { float x, y; };
struct QuatRot { Point4D Front,Right,Up; };
struct VehicleInfo
{
    Point3D     Pos,Velocity,TurnSpeed;
    QuatRot     Rotation;
};
namespace Recorder
{
    struct FrameInfo
    //~380 bytes / frame| max 45600 bytes @ 120 fps
    //max 3.7 GB raw data for 24 hours of recording, not bad..
    {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration time;
        VehicleInfo Vehicle;
        int Nitro;
        float RPM;
        int CurrentGear;
    };

    std::deque<FrameInfo> frames;
    FrameInfo g_Temp;

    void ProcessRecord()
    {
        //record vehicle data here to g_Temp
        frames.push_back(g_Temp);
        return;
    }
    //other recording code.......
};
```

What I was thinking of is, making a raw array of bytes, allocate it to the size of the deque container, copy them with memcpy from the deque to the array and then write all the array bytes to the file..

Then if I would like to read my recording data I would just read the bytes of the file and assign them to a new array, and use memcpy to copy the array contents to a deque..

and this is much like.. well.. the C way? 
There has to be some other way to do this, store the data in a file , then read it back into the deque (maybe using some C++11 features?).

How would I accomplish this?

Which approach do you recommend?

I am using windows if that matters.

Comment: `std::deque` is not required to: 1) store its memory in contiguous storage, so there will be no "memcpy from/to the deque". 2) store its memory *within the `std::deque`* object. So your plan is not going to work, period. Why are you using a `std::deque` anyway?

Comment: This memcpy thing is not even possible with deque because internally the elements are not necessarily stored in one continuous array.

Comment: @NicolBolas because I need to push_back when recording and get front() and pop_front() when replaying.

Comment: @GamErix: Why do you need to `pop_front` when replaying it? Just advance an iterator; delete the entire buffer when you've gotten all the data out.

Comment: that is an idea, but I store the last recording into the history so just to make sychronization with varying frame rates I delete the "too old" frames. when it starts playing all the other frames aren't needed anymore in the future. So I can just delete it.. ?

Comment: Anyway if you are curious how I implemented playback from recording here is the full code: http://ideone.com/lTY02r should be enough to understand everything.] else just let me know. PROTECT and UNPROTECT are just empty statements in release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly (I'm tired so please just leave a comment if I'm wrong), you want to write and read your recording to and from file.

This can easily be done with any struct:

```
struct Foo
{
   float bar;
   int baz;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Foo &foo)
{
   stream << foo.bar << " " << foo.baz;
}
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& stream, Foo &foo)
{
   stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo.bar), sizeof(bar));
   stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo.baz), sizeof(baz));
}
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& stream, Foo &foo)
{
   stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo.bar), sizeof(bar));
   stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo.baz), sizeof(baz));
}
```

You can test this with

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   foo.bar = -1.2f;
   foo.baz = 37;
    std::cout << foo << "\n";
   std::ofstream output;
   output.open("myfile", std::ios::binary);
   output << foo;
   output.close();
   std::ifstream input;
   input.open("myfile", std::ios::binary);
   input >> foo;
   input.close();
   std::cout << foo << "\n";
}
```

For further information about [`std::basic_ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) and [`std::basic::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), I recommend having a look at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: How does this store or retrieve *binary* data?

Comment: if I have a 4 byte value like "2000000000", then wouldn't it be stored just as a string with this method? which would take 10 bytes.. I can't find anything about a bytestream or something in C++

Comment: @GamErix: No, the 4 bytes are printed exactly as 4 bytes with this method. There is no "bytestream", but there are streams in binary mode, as shown in the answer above. I've added some links as reference to the methods `read` and `write`.

Comment: of that is so, then I think I could do `stream << foo.bar << foo.baz;` in the operatior `<<` or the space has to be there?

Comment: @GamErix: No. The implementation of `ostream::operator<<` is for human readable form only, hence the space for better readability (for the purpose of debugging!). Only the implementation of `ofstream::operator<<` does binary write to _file_. If you compile my example and open the file `myfile` you won't see "-1.2f37", go on and have a try.

Comment: @stefan overriding `operator<<` to write binary to a `std::ofstream` seems like a bad idea, because all other uses of `<<` on `std::ofstream` write formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` is premature optimization.

When reading stuff from disk, your bottleneck is disk IO, not copying it from one part of memory to another.

Fix your data structure so it uses fixed size data structures (instead of `int`, use a 32 bit int, etc).

Don't write `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration` in binary -- a library update could completely change the size of that without them blinking an eye or shedding a tear, let alone it's meaning.  Write out in `ms` or something, so the meaning always remains the same, in a (say) 64 bit integer.  You can then read it back into your `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration`.

Always write out a version number and structure size when serializing, so deserialization can handle even rudimentary versioning.

I'd write a "to stream" and "from stream".  "to stream" write out the version number and the size.  "from stream" reads the version number and size, loads each field that is in both the current version and the stream version, clears the remaining, then reads the remaining data off of the stream.

If you find you need more performance, you'll note that the position and angle of your car will change far more often than the gears.  In addition, dropping frames that are reasonably interpolated between existing frames would massively decrease the size of your replay format (it isn't as if you are running physics in the replay, given your description).  Finally, if you have a consistent physics model, only storing user input and replaying based on that could be possible (but that is hard to pull off).

Other insanities: SRECORDASSIGN can be replaced by just calling `operator=` on the structures in question.  Magic numbers like `0x4C` applied to pointers are silly, and are almost always replaceable with simple struct member access.

Comment: `operator =` doesnot work for my data, : `Vehicles[id] = &(*(structure*)address);` , then for example I have to do `Vehicles[id]->Pos.x = Source.Pos.x;` because `Vehicled[id] = Source` doesn't set the data... Vehicles is declared as: `VehicleInfo *Vehicles[MAX_VEHICLES];`

Comment: Btw, this can be seen also this way: `Vehicles[id] = &(*(structure*)address); // = &POINTER(structure,address);`

Comment: @GamErix `*Vehicles[id] = Source` is how you use `operator=` in that case.  Pointers and data are different things.